# C - parent performing simultaneously with his N children

Tags: c, process, synchronization

I am developing a project for an assignment and we must fork 10 children processes and let them to their specific tasks. Meanwhile the parent needs to do specific actions every 5 seconds simultaneously with the execution of his children. What is bothering me is that I know that the parent needs to wait for all his children to process before doing tasks but when I am forking multiple child through a for cycle the action that the parent makes are repeated for 10 times (as 10 is the number of forks I need to make). Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {

    switch (pids[i] = fork()) {

        case -1:
            fprintf(stderr,"Error #%03d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
            break;

        case 0:
           /*
            * child tasks
            */              
            exit(0);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

for (int k = 0; k < init_people; k++) {
    waitpid(pids[k], &returnStatus, 0);
}
```

What I would like to know is if there is a way for the parent to do his task simultaneously with the execution of his children (not before or after they have completed their own execution) but outside of the cycle so that is not repeated 10 times. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: You can do whatever you want between your two loops.

Comment: Right after the spawning loop?

Comment: After you've forked 10 children, your main process can go about its own business, executing every 5 seconds.  You'll need to think about how (whether) you need to wait for children to die, or will the be reliable and not die unexpectedly.

Comment: So in between the fork and the killing of the children the parent can do all his tasks without interfering with the child? That is just what I was looking for.. Thank you all!